# Are Ethereum text NFTs, e.g. domains all in the same namespace?

Tags: nft, ens, eth-domain

There are a couple of different Ethereum domain name creation services currently available:

- https://www.unstoppabledomains.com
- https://ens.domains
- https://www.decentraweb.org

They seem to be all based on NFT right?

But is it possible for their users to create the same domains in the Ethereum blockchain resulting in a collision? Are they offering the domains in the one namespace of the entire Ethereum or in their own namespace?

Is there Ethereum blockchain-wide coordination among them or are they just selling their own proprietary NFTs of domains that are not universally nor uniquely identifiable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ENS, the Ethereum Name Service, is the "namespace" for `.eth` names.

Other projects like Unstoppable Domains (UD), can issue and sell NFTs.  You are correct to be careful of the issues, which were also written about by the author of [ethers.js](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js):

> I’ve always had serious reservations adding UD to ethers, they were
> fully aware of my concerns and have since made the problem worse by
> adding more TLDs.

https://blog.ricmoo.com/unstoppable-and-the-infinite-sadness-203f13e86488

> For some background, the issue I was concerned with is that ENS had
> released an awesome DNSSEC registrar on Ropsten for .xyz and would be
> releasing a similar registrar for all supported TLDs. Nick gave a
> great demo at DevCon 3 in 2017 and it was epic; this would allow
> traditional web domains to interoperate seemlessly on the blockchain,
> a clear win for the Web3 universe! (FYI: it has since been launched on
> mainnet and supports over 1,300 DNS TLDs, such as .com and .org)
>
> Once .crypto becomes a gTLD (through an ICANN auction), this would
> cause a **name collision**, since if someone tries to resolve
> ricmoo.crypto, should it resolve against the ENS registry (which
> resolves against the DNS system) or the UD registry? They would almost
> certainly disagree and it is likely that whoever buys the .crypto gTLD
> is intending for it to work correctly within the blockchain ecosystem.
>
> Since then, they have been expanding the collection of TLDs being
> issued (e.g. .wallet and .nft) which exacerbates the problem,
> especially since these names will very likely be highly sought after
> by the well-funded.
>
> This then becomes not just a nuisance, but a **security concern**. A
> malicious actor could purchase an intentionally-conflicting name, in
> hopes that some services rely on the service they registered on
> allowing them to receive ether, tokens or NFT’s intended for someone
> else.

Comment: So ENS is the official .eth governance, everything else including Unstoppable Domains is just NFT creators & sellers of domain name strings that are only unique within their own smart contract? For example, while UD has a TLD .crypto, another smart contract DogeNS can also create and sell domains of TLD .crypto?

Comment: Trying to be balanced, I'd say that any contract D can copy another contract C, but it's the integrations and adoption that matter more.